# using parameterized data bound query, finding number of rows where column is true within last "x" number of days

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a query that returns the number of rows where Column "FA" is 1, between the dates of today and the parameter "x" number of days past.  The query seems to run very slow, and I'm hoping that there might be a better or faster way of making this happen.  The table this is querying has over 3 million rows, so the query gets limited in the application to look thru 259,200 rows at most, where @NewInt is 90 or less.

I have previously ran this query without exception,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM S_Data_Table
WHERE (FA = 1) AND (t_stamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()))
```

Note that the parameter is not present, instead just ran with Int of -90 as days past.

I have found that when I introduce a parameter as the number of days the t_stamp which is data type DateTime needs conversion,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM S_Data_Table
WHERE (FA = 1) AND (CONVERT(nvarchar, t_stamp, 0) >= DATEADD(DAY, - (@NewInt), GETDATE()))
```

[T_stamp pic table adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2TTj.png)

This code runs very slowly, I think it is iterating over every row, even the rows outside of the time frame, but I don't know how to find that out?

The normal result of the query when ran produces an Integer value of the number of rows that are true within the time frame.

Comment: Why would the value need converting when you provide a parameter? That doesn't make any sense. Are we missing some kind of information here? Perhaps you're passing a `datetime2` when `t_stamp` is a `date`?

Comment: For some reason it gives an error in SQL of - Failed to Convert parameter value from a Decimal to DateTime.  The data type for the t_stamp is DateTime and the type of the parameter is Int in C#.  It doesn't make sense to me either why the conversion is necessary, but it does run.

Comment: That code you've given us doesn't reproduce that error ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d1a59a86f5b990b59db35e5c58fa350)); meaning there is something else wrong here that you haven't provided us

Comment: I am using the data table adapter in visual studio 2017 .NET framework 4.6.1, query builder gives the error without the convert.  I just tested it with CAST(t_stamp AS DATETIME) and this runs as well with the parameter.

Comment: Perhaps the first query runs because it has a typographical error, and actually `t_stamp` is **not** a `datetime`? `(t_stamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -90), GETDATE()` should be `t_stamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())`

Comment: I do apologize, i did not copy it directly, I will edit the first line of code in the question.